# Storing the returned value of a function as a variable

Tags: python-3.x, function

Consider the following function:

```
def Func(x):
    Code
    return List_A, List_B, number_C
```

I want to store one of the returned values as some variable "x" so how can I go about doing this? For example, I want to store List_B as x

I tried

```
x=Func[1]
```

Detailed explanation:

```
n=int(input("blablabla"))

def Func(n)
    l_e=[]
    for i in range (1,n):
       if i%2==0:
          l_e.append(i)

    l_o=[]
    for i in range (1,n):
       if i%2>0:
          l_o.append(i)

    l=len(l_0)+len(l_e)

    return l_o, L_e, l
```

let's say I want to store the second item returned as a variable, how can I do this. I tried `x=Func[1]`, and `x=Func()[1]` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works: `x = Func()[1]`. The parentheses call the function, then the square brackets pick the item you want out of the returned tuple.

Comment: It reads, "missing positional argument."

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Does your actual `Func()` take arguments?

Comment: Yes, it takes Float type as a variable and returns two lists and a constant which depends on the two lists. Unfortunately, even when I try ```Func(x)[i]``` it just says "x is not defined. The issue is, I know "x" is defined because its set by an interactive slider.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost When you define a function, you only give the parameter names to indicate what kind of input is expected. When you call the function, you have to give values or names of variables that have been assigned values. Would it be possible to put the actual function in your question, or would that be too much code?

Comment: That's unfeasible, but I wrote a small piece of dummy code in order to clarify the issue I am having. Please have a look whenever you can, thanks.

Comment: Your answer worked; the issue was with variable assignment via ipywidgets. Thank You!